# How to bind dynamic JSON objects to PostgreSQL, using mongodb_fdw?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgres-fdw

The [Foreign Data Wrapper for MongoDB](https://github.com/citusdata/mongo_fdw) is pretty awesome! I've gotten it to work using [these instructions](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/08/05/a-look-at-FDWs/), apart from:

- an object with dynamic fields within it - which PostgreSQL type to use for such?

  {
    "key1": some,
    ...
  }
- an array of objects - which PostgreSQL type to use for such? The length of the array may vary, but the objects are uniform in their inner structure.

  [ { "a": 1 }, { "a": 2 }, { "a": 3 } ]

I found [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/EnterpriseDB/the-nosql-way-in-postgres) on JSON capabilities in recent PostgreSQL versions. Neat. But `BSON`, `JSON` or `JSONB` don't seem to be recognized by the FDW as SQL data types.

If I use:

```
  CREATE FOREIGN TABLE t6
  (
      "aaa.bbb" JSON    -- 'bbb' is an array of JSON objects
  )
  SERVER mongo_server OPTIONS(...);

  SELECT "aaa.bbb" AS bbb FROM t6;
```

I get:

```
  psql:6.sql:152: ERROR:  cannot convert bson type to column type
HINT:  Column type: 114
```

The normal types `TEXT`, `FLOAT` etc. work.

Comment: *But BSON, JSON or JSONB don't seem to be recognized by the FDW as SQL data types.* -- What did you tried? What was the error messge, if there was one? What was the (unexpected) output, if there was no error?

Comment: ok, added some details

Comment: According to [this similar feature request](https://github.com/citusdata/mongo_fdw/issues/19) the `mongo_fdw` you use won't be updated; but there is an [EnterpriseDB fork](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw) which allows you to use the `json` sql type (only that) where you have json array or object in your document (according to [their current sources](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw/blob/a159d42bd1b2190c47e8b97b5939415e07389d24/mongo_fdw.c#L1341)).

Comment: Sweet, thanks for making sense to this! Will try the other fdw flavour.

Comment: @pozs I tried the other flavor. It was rather messy to build (on OS X + Homebrew), and only the 'legacy' sub-flavor offers JSON support in the code. Even so, I did not get to actually see my data using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EnterpriseDB fork](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw/) does it, as @pozs was pointing out. Just mark your data as `JSON` type.

However, the build system is rather bizarre to my taste, and does not really give you right errors for missing build components (it's obviously Linux-based and simply expects you to have a bunch of tools without properly checking for them).

Here's how I managed to build it on OS X + [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
$ brew install libtool libbson autoconf automake
$ ./autogen.sh --with-legacy
```

Note that the `--with-meta` variant does *not* provide JSON support, which was the reason I went for this fork anyways.

ref. https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw/issues/20